# Erro na comparação de caracteres com strcmp

Tags: c

Na questão pede que se forme um par de tênis Direito e Esquerdo por isso usei o strcmp para comparar,utilizei o 1 por que as strings tem que ser diferentes,mas não tive o resultado que a questão pediu.

Link para a questão https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/pt/problems/view/1245

Aqui está o meu código

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(void)
{
  int i, teste, j, c = 0;
  while(scanf("%d", &teste) != EOF)
  {
    c = 0;
    int vet[teste];
    char nome[teste][100];
    for(i = 0; i < teste; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d %s", &vet[i], nome[i]);
    }
    for(i = 0; i < teste; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < teste; j++)
        {
            if(vet[i] == vet[j])
            {
                if(strcmp(nome[i], nome[j]) == 1)
                {
                    c++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    printf("%d\n", c);
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Você está percorrendo o vetor vet errado. Na sua logica se existir 1 milhão de botas 40 D e no final houver apenas uma bota 40 E, seu resultado irá mostrar que existe 1 milhão de pares. O certo seria você marcar se uma bota já possui o pé encontrado.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(void)
{
  int i, teste, j, c = 0;
  while(scanf("%d", &teste) != EOF)
 {
   c = 0;
   int vet[teste];
   char nome[teste][100];
   //Criei esse vetor que marcar as botas
   int vestido[teste];
   for (i = 0 ; i < teste; i++)
   {
       vestido[i] = 0;
   }
   for(i = 0; i < teste; i++)
   {
       scanf("%d %s", &vet[i], nome[i]);
   }
   for(i = 0; i < teste; i++)
   {
       for(j = 0; j < teste ; j++)
       {
           //aqui eu verifico se a bota foi encontrada
           if(vet[i] == vet[j] && vestido[i]!=1 & vestido[j]!=1)
           {
               if(strcmp(nome[i], nome[j]) == 1)
               {
                   c++;
                   //aqui eu marco se a bota encontrada
                   vestido[i] = 1;
                   vestido[j] = 1;
               }
           }
       }
   }
  printf("%d\n", c);
 }
}
```

Testei e foi aceito, deve haver várias formas de melhorar o código e diminuir a computação.

Comment: A complexidade do codigo é em ordem de O(n²), mas há como fazer em O(n).